# AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 -- Support for EventBridge Scheduler?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I would like to use the AWS EventBridge Scheduler service, which seems to have been released just a few months ago. Normally, we use the **AWS SDK for JavaScript v3** for interacting with AWS services, but the v3 SDK does not seem to have any support for the Scheduler:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-eventbridge/index.html

Firstly, if that's no true, can anyone point me to an SDK reference for the Scheduler?

Secondly, if it is true, then I guess using the HTTP API is the next best option for using this service from Node.js?

I assume that AWS will eventually add support for the Scheduler to the SDK... does anyone happen to know when that might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. For some reason the Scheduler is not part of the EventBridge npm package, but this standalone one instead:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-scheduler/index.html